# Removing global from function

Tags: php, pdo

I've VERY NEW to PDO.  I created the below function, but I read having the global database ($dbo) is a bad idea.  The code works and outputs what I want it too.  Any suggestions on how to improve/fix?

```
function langString($lang_id) { 
    global $dbo;
    $lang_result=$dbo->prepare("SELECT lang_string FROM lang WHERE lang_id=:lang_id");
    $lang_result->bindParam(":lang_id",$lang_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);
    if($lang_result->execute()){ 
        $lang_row = $lang_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo "<br><br>$lang_row->lang_string";
    }
}

echo langString(3);
```

Comment: Over-reliance on global vars is poor practice.  Your case isn't a tragedy because you will generally only have one database connection in a script so there's little room for confusion.  The alternative here is to pass it as a param `function langString($lang_id, $dbo){}`

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It literally took me all day to convert this function.  Learning this is a slow process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the variable as an argument to the function

```
function langString($lang_id, $dbo) {   
    $lang_result=$dbo->prepare("SELECT lang_string FROM lang WHERE lang_id=:lang_id");
    $lang_result->bindParam(":lang_id",$lang_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);
    if($lang_result->execute()){ 
        $lang_row = $lang_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo "<br><br>$lang_row->lang_string";
    }
}

echo langString(3, $dbo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch with the accepted answer is that you will end up trailing your database round every function as a parameter. This results in longer lists of parameters and as you get more stuff starts to look messy.

An alternative method is to make a Singleton which you can call to get the database connection e.g. Normally large projects will use this for more than just accessing the DB but here's a simple example

```
class DatabaseProvider {
     private static $database;
     private $dbo;
     private function __construct() {
         //Here's where you do your PDO connection creation
         $this->dbo= new PDO()....;
     }
     public static function getDatabase() {
         if(!isset(self::$database) {
               self::$database = new DatabaseProvider();
         }
         return $database->dbo;
     }
}
```

Then you just call `DatabaseProvider::getInstance()` which returns the pdo object

Comment: -1 for substituting one form of global for another.  Especially since the OP is new to PHP, and OO code will likely just confuse them more.

Comment: +1 for introducing the OP to an OOP approach to solving a problem.

Comment: If you do not implement Service locator or Dependency injection allowing one to replace DatabaseProvider with something else, this code has no benefits over using `global`. You still need to initialize `DatabaseProvider` and it can be accessed as global from any part of the system. `DatabaseProvider` gives no facade for PDO object, just as using `global`.

Comment: I'd argue that really, the database **is** a global system which needs to be accessible from most places. Directly referencing a global scope value is a little ugly. Passing `dbo` into every function essentially global-ises the scope of it anyway.

As I said, the fact that it's just the DB means the solution is going to be a little ugly in any case. The singleton object is more useful when you have Language translation functions, file loaders and other systems.

Giving a solution that is bad only because they will understand it isn't really what SO is about..

Answer (score -2):

Use an include file...

Put your variables or even create a db object in the include, and then you can call it from anywhere.

```
function langString($lang_id) { 

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dbconnect.php"); //Put your vars in this document

    $lang_result=$dbo->prepare("SELECT lang_string FROM lang WHERE lang_id=:lang_id");
    $lang_result->bindParam(":lang_id",$lang_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);
    if($lang_result->execute()){ 
        $lang_row = $lang_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo "<br><br>$lang_row->lang_string";
    }
}

echo langString(3);
```

Comment: Assuming langString() is not the only function using database connection and that the connection is created at a top level (hence global in the first example), this is not a good advice. Thanks for trying.

Comment: You don't need to vote me down for that. Using an include would work fine.